# Comparing function to number in lua

Tags: lua

```
    start = io.read()
    if start == "start" then
    xpr = 50
    xp = 75
    function level()
        if xp >= xpr and level < 50 then
            xpr = xpr * 1.5
            level = level + 1
            io.write("Congrats you somehow didn't die and lose every bit of progress!", "\n")
            io.write("By the way your level is ", level, "\n")
            io.write("Now you must allocate your skill points now", "\n")
            sp = 6
            io.write("Strength: ", "\n")
            strsp = io.read()
            stre = stre + strsp
            if strsp < sp then
                io.write("There are only",sp,"skill points", "\n")
                str = str + 6
            end
            io.write("Dexterity: ", "\n")
            dexsp = io.read()
            dex = dex + dexsp
            if dexsp < sp then
                io.write("There are only",sp,"skill points", "\n")
                dex = dex + 6
            end
            io.write("Constuion: ", "\n")
            consp = io.read()
            con = con + consp
            if consp < sp then
                io.write("There are only",sp,"skill points", "\n")
                con = con + 6
            end
            io.write("Intelligence: ", "\n")
            intsp = io.read()
            int = int + intsp
            if intsp < sp then
                io.write("There are only",sp,"skill points", "\n")
                int = int + 6
            end
            io.write("Wisdom: ", "\n")
            wissp = io.read()
            wis = wis + wissp
            if wissp < sp then
                io.write("There are only",sp,"skill points", "\n")
                wis = wis + 6
            end
            io.write("Charisma: ", "\n")
            chasp = io.read()
            cha = cha + chasp
            if chasp < sp then
                io.write("There are only",sp,"skill points", "\n")
                cha = cha + 6
            end
        end
    end
 end
 
print(level(xp))
```

This is my code. But it comes back as

> lua: attempt to compare function with number

How can I fix this?

Comment: `if xp >= xpr and level < 50 then` - you've just defined `level` to be a function and it shadows over (presumably) a previous variable `level`.  And by the way, the stack trace points to the *actual line* where this happens; this is important information that you omitted.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing a function with a number doesn't make any sense.

`function level() end` is syntactic sugar for `level = function () end`. Just in case you're wondering why `level` is a function value.

`level < 50` compares your global function `level` with `50`.

You call `level(xp)` but `level` doesn't have any parameters btw.

Either rename the function or the variable you want to compare with `50`.
Either way you need to initialize that variable with a number value or you'll get an error for comparing nil with a number.

Comment: I'll add parameters to level and see if changing the name will work thank you